# Macros from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: excel

```
=IF(G10<>"",IF(H10<>"",ROUND(@RHtoGR(G10,H10,0),0),""),"")
```

I have been using this macros to get the grains per pound from relative humanity and temperature. I upgraded my computer from a 32 bit to 64 bit and now it gives me a #name error. can anyone help me with this?

I have looked online and i have come up empty handed.

Comment: What is `@RHtoGR`? Is that a custom function? It looks like you've posted a worksheet formula. What is the VBA you are asking about? Post the context in which this formula is called. Edit your question to do that. Do NOT post this into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `#Name?` error means that a name of a function or reference used in a formula is not recognised. This is probably referring to the `@RHtoGR`, which looks like it's a custom function. The `@` character has a specific meaning in modern Excel and cannot not be used in a function name.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.